# Find pattern and filter the start location

Tags: r, filter, location

I would like to find the location of a pattern AND filter the location.

I'm looking for a function to return the start location of the pattern "gaaa" between 30 and 34 for each row.

I explain, for the moment here is what I have as a result with the function str_locate_all :

```
library(stringr)
Sequence <- data.frame(All = c("ggcgaagcagugcucccaguguuuuagagcuagaaauagcaaguuaaaauaaggcuaguccguuaucaacuugaaaaaguggcaccgagucggugcuu",
"aggacaacucgcuccacggccguuuuagagcuagaaauagcaaguuaaaauaaggcuaguccguuaucaacuugaaaaaguggcaccgagucggugcuu",
"cugaaauggcagcagaaacguuuuagagcuagaaauagcaaguuaaaauaaggcuaguccguuaucaacuugaaaaaguggcaccgagucggugcaacaaa",
"ggucaaagaggaggagcucguuuuagagcuagaaauagcaaguuaaaauaaggcuaguccguuaucaacuugaaaaaguggcaccgagucggugcuu"))
str_locate_all(pattern = 'gaaa', Sequence$All)

[[1]]
     start end
[1,]    33  36
[2,]    73  76

[[2]]
     start end
[1,]    34  37
[2,]    74  77

[[3]]
     start end
[1,]     3   6
[2,]    15  18
[3,]    32  35
[4,]    72  75

[[4]]
     start end
[1,]    32  35
[2,]    72  75
```

Here is what I would like to have as a result:

```
       start
1         33
2         34
3         32
4         32
```

Thanks you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
Sequence$start <- 
  sapply(str_locate_all(pattern = 'gaaa', Sequence$All),
         function(z) { ind <- which(30 <= z[,1] & z[,1] <= 34); if (length(ind)) z[ind[1],1] else NA })
Sequence[,2,drop=FALSE]
#   start
# 1    33
# 2    34
# 3    32
# 4    32
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way. It uses the output of the `str_locate_all` instruction in the question and filters it in a `lapply` loop.

```
found <- str_locate_all(pattern = 'gaaa', Sequence$All)
found <- lapply(found, function(x){
  y <- x[, 'start']
  data.frame(start = y[y >= 30 & y <= 34])
})
do.call(rbind, found)
#  start
#1    33
#2    34
#3    32
#4    32
```

Here is another way. It searches only a sub string of the original string.

```
first <- 30
last <- 34
tmp <- substr(Sequence$All, first, last + nchar('gaaa') - 1)
data.frame(start = str_locate(pattern = 'gaaa', tmp)[, 1] + first - 1)
```

#Timings

Here are the timings of the 3 answers available so far, [r2evans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61856988/8245406), mine and [tmfmnk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61856988/8245406).

I only post the results with larger input, since that's what should make the timings important.

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

r2evans <- function(){
  Sequence$start <-
    sapply(str_locate_all(pattern = 'gaaa', Sequence$All),
           function(z) { ind <- which(30 <= z[,1] & z[,1] <= 34); if (length(ind)) z[ind[1],1] else NA })
  Sequence[,2,drop=FALSE]
}

rui <- function(){
  first <- 30
  last <- 34
  tmp <- substr(Sequence$All, first, last + nchar('gaaa') - 1)
  data.frame(start = str_locate(pattern = 'gaaa', tmp)[, 1] + first - 1)
}

tmfmnk <- function(){
  map_dfr(.x = str_locate_all(pattern = "gaaa", Sequence$All),
          ~ as.data.frame(.x) %>%
            filter(start %in% c(30:34)),
          .id = "ID")
}


library(microbenchmark)

for(i in 1:8) Sequence <- rbind(Sequence, Sequence)
dim(Sequence)
#[1] 1024    1

mb <- microbenchmark(
  revans = f1(),
  rui = f2()
  tmfmnk = f3()
)
print(mb, unit = 'relative', order = 'median')
#Unit: relative
#    expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq       max neval
#     rui    1.00000    1.00000    1.00000    1.00000    1.00000   1.00000   100
# r2evans   19.66135   17.52724   16.28008   15.47317   16.20747   5.60779   100
#  tmfmnk 1529.51644 1235.86285 1079.56958 1073.49131 1072.39265 317.95638   100
```

Answer (score 1):

One `dplyr` and `purrr` solution could be:

```
map_dfr(.x = str_locate_all(pattern = "gaaa", Sequence$All),
        ~ as.data.frame(.x) %>%
         filter(start %in% c(30:34)),
        .id = "ID")

  ID start end
1  1    33  36
2  2    34  37
3  3    32  35
4  4    32  35
```